# Halting Problem, Typed Version: A Headache

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

After many years, I have been revisiting the venerable old Halting Problem and the self-referential / diagonalization “party trick” that shows that there is no Turing Machine able to solve it.

I was bothered by the fact that it was, and continues to be, stated in an untyped manner, and thus is a bit sloppy for my tastes.

Let's call `HALTP` be the (actually, "an") always-halting Turing Machine (TM) which can decide whether a pair *[Turing Machine, Input]* is a combination that halts (the P is coming from the [P convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_convention).)

Once typing is considered when one feeds the representation of `HALTP` (actualy, the representation of a slightly modified version of `HALTP`) to  the `HALTP` Turing machine itself, things fall a bit apart.

## Preliminaries

(Actually you can just go directly to "typing" as everything here is rather unsurprising)

- All the TMs that we are talking about are ‘a-machines’, as opposed to the (more interesting) ‘o-machines’ which have access to “Oracle Tapes”. They are implementations of functions taking input, running to completion (or not) and yielding output.
- There is an Universal TM called `UTM_L`, able to simulate any other TM, if that TM has been expressed as some finite string of symbols chosen from a finite alphabet $L$ (which is assumed to be possible).
- A string from $L^*$ representing the Turing Machine with the name `MYTM` is written `<MYTM>`, and thus the "code" of `MYTM`.
- Not every string from $L^*$ represents an actual TM (some strings have no meaning and cannot be run by `UTM_L`). We mark the subset of valid TMs as $L^*_{valid} \subset L^*$ (I state w/o proof that $L^*_{valid}$ this is a decidable language).
- We assume that all the TM are run by `UTM_L`, which also is a multitape machine with disjoint symbol sets for each tape. The following tapes are assumed to exist:

  - ✇I = Input Tape containing elements from a language $TREE$ (see below).
  - ✇P = Program Tape containing a `<TM>` from a $L^*_{valid}$ to be emulated.
  - ✇W = Work Tape (not further examined)
  - ✇O = Output Tape containing strings from the 4-element language: { ⊥, ⊤, ⚠, ∅ }. ✇O originally only contains ∅, which is replaced by one of the other three words.
- *With* loss of generality we only consider TMs which accept / reject elements of a given language. The functions they implement are not "constructive".
- Every TM accepts elements of a language $TREE$ on ✇I. $TREE$ is informally defined as: "The bracketed expressions build from comma-separated `<TM>`, strings from a language $W*$ built from a finite set of symbols disjoint from $L$, the elements of which we denote with `<w>` and elements from the language $TREE$". For example: `[<TM1>, [], <w0>, [<w1>, <w2>]]`.
- Finally, we define:

  - DECIDER TM: The TM is presented with `<w>` on ✇I. It always halts and replaces the ∅ sign on ✇O with:

    - ✇O = ⊤ if TM accepts `<w>`
    - ✇O = ⊥ if TM rejects `<w>`
    - ✇O = ⚠ if there is a type error (see below)
  - RECOGNIZER TM: The TM is presented with `<w>` on ✇I. It may or may not halt.

    - ✇O = ⊤ if TM halts and accepts `<w>`
    - ✇O = ⊥ if TM halts and rejects `<w>`
    - ✇O = ⚠ if there is a type error 8see below)
    - ✇O = ∅ if TM does not halt (a bit of a language abuse as it just means that the original ∅ symbol on ✇O will never be replaced).

## Typing

Now, we implement “typing” in as follows:

We add “type judgements” to our Turing Machine description toolset. Type judgements are not found on tapes, they are part of the specification of TMs.

We need just two type judgements:

- `<tm>: TM` – The word `<tm>` on the ✇I represents a TM from $L^*_{valid}$
- `<x>: TREE` – The word `<x>` on the ✇I is an element from $TREE$.

We assume that when a TM is run on input `<w>`, i.e. when we compute `TM(<w>)`, the TM performs a type check and decides whether `<w>` passes all type judgements given in its definition. If `<w>` does not pass, the TM outputs ⚠ on the ✇O and halts.

## Define HALTP

So, we suppose that there is a TM called `HALTP` with obeys the following specification:

---

- `HALTP( [<tm>: TM, <x>: TREE] )` meaning that `UTM_L` implementing it shall expect

  - On ✇P: `<HALTP>`
  - On ✇I: The finite word from $TREE$ represented by `[<tm>, <x>]` where `<tm>` and `<x>` fulfill the type judgements.

If the initial type check on ✇I fails, ✇O = ⚠

Otherwise, we expect flawless performance and halt-in-all cases and:

- ✇O = ⊤ if the TM given by `<tm>` halts and accepts `<x>`
- ✇O = ⊥ if the TM does not accept `<x>` (does not halt or rejects `<x>`)

---

## The Problem

In the diagonalization approach, we feed `<HALTP>` to `HALTP` (actually `<the complement of HALTP>` to `HALTP`, but let’s keep going). So let’s try that here:

**Does `HALTP` halt on input x?**

`HALTP( [<HALTP>: TM, <x>: TREE] )`

But what is `<x>`?

`<x>` must evidently be something that can be given to the TM represented by the first argument i.e. `HALTP`, otherwise this call is entirely meaningless.

`HALTP` expects and argument matching `( [<tm>: TM, <x>: TREE] )`

so we need to actually call `HALTP` like this, as we want to call `HALTP` on `HALTP`:

**Does `HALTP` halt on input itself on input x?**

`HALTP( [<HALTP>: TM, [ <HALTP>: TM, <x’>: TREE]] )`

But what is `<x’>`?

`<x>` must evidently be something that can be given to the TM represented by the second argument i.e. `HALTP`, otherwise this call is entirely meaningless.

so we really need:

**Does `HALTP` halt on input itself on input itself on input x?**

`HALTP( [<HALTP>: TM, [ <HALTP>: TM, [ <HALTP>: TM, <x’’>: TREE]]] )`

and so on ad infinitum.

The effort to build a meaningful argument to `HALTP` seems to fail due to an infinite regress and the question "what happens if we give HALTP to HALTP" does not make sense because giving `HALTP` to `HALTP` is nonsensical.

The textbook proof seems to absolutely ignore this problem, it assumes that calling

`HALTP( <HALTP>, <HALTP> )`

makes sense.

For example, the extract below is from Michael Sipser’s *“Introduction to the Theory of Computation, 2nd Edition”*, 2006, p. 179. In particular, it compares "running `HALTP` on itself" with a compiler in Pascal compiling the compiler for Pascal – but that is not the same thing at all because the argument to the compiler is meaningful **without an additional argument to the compiler-to-be-compiled**.

How to to fix that?

[image: Extract from Sipser’s "Introduction to the Theory of Computation"]

Comment: Perhaps you'll like this proof more: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/35683/683.

Comment: I'm wondering why do you associate "being stated in an untyped manner" with "sloppy"?  Many mathematical proofs are stated in an untyped manner.  Perhaps understanding that better might help me understand your sense of unease/discomfort with this proof?

Comment: The halting problem for the typed Turing machines is undecidable. It is not hard to give it a new proof or adapt the previous proof.

Answer (score 4):

In general, a type system can affect the expressivity of a programming language and make it less expressive -- sometimes to the point of turning a Turing-complete language into a non-Turing-complete language.  (In other words, the introduction of a type system can in some cases restrict what can be expressed in the language enough that the halting problem becomes decidable.)

A crucial aspect of Turing machines is that you can build a [universal Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine).  Another way to think of that is that Turing machines are expressive enough that you can construct a Turing machine that acts as an interpreter for Turing machines: if you provide it a description of a Turing machine (as bits), then it will simulate execution of that Turing machine.  Another way to describe this is that Turing machines basically can implement [`eval`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval).  Moreover, once you can implement `eval`, then the halting problem becomes undecidable.

However, `eval` is incompatible with some static type systems: it takes as input a bit-string, and outputs a value whose type is not statically known.  Many static type systems can't handle that.  So, if you introduce a static type system without being sufficiently careful, then you might have (without realizing it) restricted expressivity enough that `eval` can no longer be implemented, an interpreter cannot be implemented, etc.

In that case, the standard proof of the halting theorem might no longer apply to such a restricted model of computation -- and that might be because it is so limited that it can no longer model many of the computations we care about.  I couldn't understand all the fine details of your proposed type system, but I suspect that might be happening with your proposal.  So, it's no surprise if the standard proof of the halting theorem no longer applies to your model of computation.  It's possible that the halting problem for your restricted model of computation might be decidable, but that doesn't say anything about the decidability of the halting problem for Turing machines.

Comment: Thanks D.W. I have to think about this some more and possibly change my question's wording to make things simpler/clearer. There is some kind of spark that's missing.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer, I confess that I didn't understand all the details of your question -- it is pretty long and I didn't have time to study a post of that length in detail.  I apologize if I missed a key point of your question.